# Style error when using Material ExposedDropdownMenu

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

When I try to use

```
@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu
```

Android Studio asks me to create a style

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type frais"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I expect to see a `ExposedDropdownMenu` style in the `TextInputLayout`, but actually Android Studio asks me to create this style

Answer (score 2):

The [**Exposed Dropdown Menu**](https://material.io/design/components/menus.html#exposed-dropdown-menu) material component has been introduced in the release version:

#### 1.1.0-alpha06

> Dark Theme, exposed dropdown menu, badges, and more!

Source: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0-alpha06

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Add dependency in app gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Step 2: Change/Modify App level theme.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Step 3: Then use material controls in your app.

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                  style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="District">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/actDistrict"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<desired version>'` into your app gradle file (which I was).

more info, you can refer to [Getting started with Material Components for Android doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0-alpha06/docs/getting-started.md).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            ...>
```

to

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout      
 style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
         ...>
```

The [**`com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) is included in the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

[image]